Is there an analog to eccentricity for quadric surfaces?
Since all conic sections of the same eccentricity are similar, eccentricity provides a great way to develop intuition for conics.  It makes it easy to see, for example, how a parabola is the limiting case between ellipses and hyperbolas, or to understand the projections of a cone.
Is there anything similar for quadric surfaces? Of course, I doubt a single parameter would suffice, but I believe two parameters might suffice:
Start with an ellipsoid.  It's $x, y,$ and $z$ projections are all ellipses, giving us three planar eccentricities, all $\leq 1$.  Are these three degrees of freedom? Or, up to similarity, are there only two degrees of freedom, with the third achievable via scaling?
Now take a hyperbolic parabaloid.  It seems to have only one degree of freedom: The eccentricity of the hyperbola.  Of course, a true parameterization of the quadric surfaces must account for all the surfaces under one paramater-schema.
Is there a way to unite all the quadrics under one or more eccentricity-like parameters?

Update
Of course, as Ted Shifrin notes, "the standard coordinate axes/planes are not geometrically meaningful."  This is not an problem: By $x, y, z$ planes, we simply mean 3 planes that are:

Mutually orthogonal
Any principal axis of the surface lies in one of the planes


For starters, the standard coordinate axes/planes are not geometrically meaningful.

@TedShifrin Updated to explain what I mean by $x, y, z$

Should you not be using the principal axes as the chosen axes?

@TedShifrin Yes, I am for simplicity assuming the principal axes are $x, y, z$; this simplifies things and comes at no cost, because of the obvious orthogonal transformation
